# EventSubscriber not trigger

Tags: 9, event-subscribers

I have a `EventSubscriber` which I want to trigger before the entity is saved (to alter the title). But I can't figure why it doesn't work. I got back the projet, do the migration from D8 to D9. Is it possible that is came from the D9 migration ?

I could simply add the `hook_entity_presave` in a module, but I guess it's cleaner to add that in an `EventSubscriber`

```
  my_module.entity_event_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\my_module\EventSubscriber\EntityEventSubscriber
    arguments: ['@entity_type.manager','@entity_field.manager']
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Here my event

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\hook_event_dispatcher\Event\Entity\EntityPresaveEvent;
use Drupal\hook_event_dispatcher\HookEventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class EntityEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  private $em;
  private $entityFieldManager;

  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $em, EntityFieldManagerInterface $entityFieldManager) {
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->entityFieldManager = $entityFieldManager;
  }
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [
      HookEventDispatcherInterface::ENTITY_PRE_SAVE => 'entitySave',
    ];
  }

  /**
   *
   */
  public function entitySave(EntityPresaveEvent $event) {
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityInterface $entity */
    $entity = $event->getEntity();
    $entity_type_id = $entity->getEntityTypeId();
    $bundle = $entity->bundle();
    if (in_array($entity_type_id, ['node', 'node_custom'])) {
        /// logic
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"I could simply add the hook_entity_presave in a module, but I guess it's cleaner to add that in an EventSubscriber"* - No, as long as core provides this API in hooks and you need an extra module to dispatch the event (via the same hook by the way), this is definitely not a *cleaner* solution.

Comment: Isn't the EventSubscriber native to Drupal ?

Comment: The hook_event_dispatcher isn't native...

Comment: Oh yeah, it's a (n old) module ! Didn't notice that.... So how to I use the presave in the subscriber ?

Comment: Use hook_entity_presave.

Comment: If you still want to use the subscriber, fire the event by yourself in the presave hook. Or - if it's your custom entity - just implement 'public function preSave(EntityStorageInterface $storage)'

Answer (score 1):

[Hook Event Dispatcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_event_dispatcher)
 in version `8.x-2.x` have had their `EntityPresaveEvent` namespace switched from `hook_event_dispatcher` to `core_event_dispatcher` in [Move Entity events to core_event_dispatcher](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/hook_event_dispatcher/-/commit/f6d911938f5141919bf9f63a9a8d38f83e202d18).

Please change these references accordingly:

**Before:**

```
use Drupal\hook_event_dispatcher\Event\Entity\EntityPresaveEvent;
```

**After:**

```
use Drupal\core_event_dispatcher\Event\Entity\EntityPresaveEvent;
```

Also ensure you install the new `core_event_dispatcher` dependency.

See also [ExampleEntityEventSubscribers.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/hook_event_dispatcher/-/blob/8.x-2.x/examples/ExampleEntityEventSubscribers.php) for example usages.